# timed background change for whole body background

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a background change on queue. This is what I have to change the background:

```
var bgarray = new Array();
var curbg = 0;

function getBackgrounds() {
    var totalbg = 4;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalbg; i++) {
        bgarray[i] = 'url("img/' + i + '.jpeg")';
    }
}

function changeBackground() {
    debugger;

    if (curbg === (bgarray.length - 1)) {
        curbg = 0;
    }

    var bgurl = bgarray[curbg];
    curbg++;

    $(document.body).animate({
        'background-image': bgurl
    }, 1000);
}
```

I've used `setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);` in my calling code, yet it just will not change the background.

The console is not logging any errors and the files definitely exist.

Any idea why there is no change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var bgarray = ['https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AXkkbmFRErs/TjCZIWGawfI/AAAAAAAAAlk/lT8yTGBYh38/s1600/Rick-Roll3.png','http://cdn.hitfix.com/photos/5203303/Rick-Roll-Mash-Up.jpg','http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view2/1569461/rick-roll-o.gif','https://media4.giphy.com/media/lKm3FhZ6xMkFO/200_s.gif'];
var curbg = 0;

function changeBackground() {
    curbg++;
    if (curbg === (bgarray.length)) {
        curbg = 0;
    }
    var bgurl = bgarray[curbg];
    $(document.body).css('background-image','url("'+bgurl+'")');
}

setInterval(changeBackground,4000);
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-image 1s;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is this what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Yes! Loving the images! Thank you

Comment: @Astrify I'm glad to help! :)